# Getting `xprop` of child/client window given X ID of frame

Tags: linux, bash, xorg, window-managers

I'd like to run the command `xprop -id [window_id]`.

However, assume that for some odd reason, I only have access to the `window_id` of the **frame** for the window I'm after(i.e. the window manager's frame for the window as opposed to the window itself).

How can I tell `xprop` that the `-id` is for the frame not the client window, and that I want the client window? Sort of the inverse to `xprop -frame` which will grab the information for the window you click on's *frame* as opposed to the window.

Am I stuck with somehow parsing `xwininfo -children [frame_id]` to extract the child window id to pass that into `xprop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just doing:

```
xprop -id `xwininfo -children -id [frame_id] | grep -o '^ \+0x[0-9a-f]\+'`
```

The `xwininfo -children -id [frame_id]` lists the children and the `grep` extracts the child ID (for my particular problem I may assume there is just one child per frame).

Answer (score 1):

If `xwininfo` and `xprop` are too limited for what you want to do, try checking their source code and writing an X11 program for this. If C is too much trouble, then try some other language's Xlib or XCB bindings, like Python's `xpyb`.

- http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xwininfo/tree/
- http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xprop/tree

Comment: Thanks, but I'm restricted to using xwininfo or xprop as stated - this would be pretty easy to whip up in X11/C but I don't have that luxury.